# image as preview as well as link to other pages

Tags: jquery, image, href, preview

I have one problem, I want to make my images to display preview but onclick it should go to some other pages, I have used jquery plugin for image preview but the anchor link href is an image so when you click it it goes image url. I want it to go some other page.

```
<li><a href="images/bc1.png" class="preview"><img src="images/bc1.png" alt="bc1"/></a><a href="#" class="tag">Tag Name</a></li>
```

The preview plugin requires using `href="images"`.

Please help me if you know the answer.

Comment: Which JQuery plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/p8qSf/

## **HTML**

```
<a id="link" href="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQB0l0xnGOHuRPFMMMi-OVg39nfAU1Ogvxr7Okk7DD8ZpqlMF9r">
    <img src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQB0l0xnGOHuRPFMMMi-OVg39nfAU1Ogvxr7Okk7DD8ZpqlMF9r"/>
</a>
```

## **js**

```
$('#link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(location).attr('href','http://google.com');
});
```